# Transfer a folder to FTP server without iterating through all files

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to transfer an entire folder to FTP server using PHP.

Right now I am using this code:

```
function ftp_copyAll($conn_id, $src_dir, $dst_dir) { 
  if (is_dir($dst_dir)) { 
    return "<br> Dir <b> $dst_dir </b> Already exists  <br> "; 
  } else { 
    $d = dir($src_dir); 
    ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dst_dir);   
    echo "create dir <b><u> $dst_dir </u></b><br>"; 
    while($file = $d->read()) { // do this for each file in the directory 
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { // to prevent an infinite loop
        if (is_dir($src_dir."/".$file)) { // do the following if it is a directory 
          ftp_copyAll($conn_id, $src_dir."/".$file, $dst_dir."/".$file); // recursive part 
        } else { 
          $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $dst_dir."/".$file, $src_dir."/".$file, FTP_BINARY); // put the files 
          echo "creat files::: <b><u>".$dst_dir."/".$file ." </u></b><br>"; 
        } 
      } 
      ob_flush() ; 
      sleep(1);  
    } 
    $d->close(); 
  } 
  return "<br><br><font size=3><b>All Copied  ok </b></font>"; 
}
```

But is it possible to transfer the entire folder without iterating through the files? Because I have about 100+ files and PHP is taking lot of time for the transfer.

Is there any way to increase the speed of transfer?

Answer (score 0):

No there's no other generic way supported by a common FTP server.

---

Except that you pack the files (zip, gzip, etc) locally, upload them and unpack remotely.

But if you have an FTP access only, you do not have a way to unpack them remotely anyway. Unless the FTP server explicitly allows that. Either by allowing you to execute an arbitrary remote shell command (typically not allowed) or using a proprietary "unpack" extension (very few servers do support that).

---

The FTP protocol is generally very inefficient for transferring a large amount of small files, because each file transfer has quite an overhead for opening a separate data transfer connection.